# Automatically delete inactive users after 2 months

Tags: users, mysql, user-meta, customization

I am trying to modify this [function](http://www.wpcodesnippet.com/functions/automatically-delete-users-7-days-wordpress/):

```
// automatically delete users after 7 days in wordpress
function wcs_auto_delete_users() {
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE datediff( now(), user_registered ) > 7" );
if ( $oldUsers = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_N ) ) {
    foreach ( $oldUsers as $user_id ) {
        wp_delete_user( $user_id[0] );
    }
}
}
add_action( 'wcs_daily_clean_database', 'wcs_auto_delete_users' );

wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'wcs_daily_clean_database' );
```

to work differently instead — I want it automatically delete users who haven't been active in, say, 2 months. I have a plugin that tracks user activity and stores the data in wp_usermeta.  Example:

```
user_id = 2; meta_key = wp_wp_kc_last_active_time; meta_value = 1422796627
```

This is the query that I've come up with:

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_wp_kc_last_active_time' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( second, now(), TIMESTAMP(SELECT meta_value) ) > 5184000
```

But it's not selecting the right IDs. What should I change to make it work?

Comment: I would recommend disabling inactive user accounts first, rather than deleting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wrong because your third argument to TIMESTAMPDIFF is incorrect.

You should be using meta_value instead of SELECT meta_value.

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_wp_kc_last_active_time' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( second, now(), TIMESTAMP(meta_value) ) > 5184000;
```

Try that and see if the results start looking correct.

I just checked over the [mySQL Date Function Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) and you appear to be doing this wrong.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_wp_kc_last_active_time' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(meta_value) ) > 2;
```

Or Maybe...

```
global $wpdb;

$query = <<<SQL
 SELECT user_id 
 FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} 
 WHERE 
    meta_key = 'wp_wp_kc_last_active_time'
    AND DATEDIFF( NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME( meta_value ) ) > 60
SQL;

$query = $wpdb->prepare( $query );
```

Which should gather the right users. If not, try it without the datediff statement and see if anything is returned. If not, then something is amiss with the meta_key (e.g. is it really wp_wp_... or just wp_kc_...)

Comment: Nope, no syntax error this time, but: "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)", and there're definitely users who haven't visited the site in over 2 months.

Comment: Try the new query I added. I believe your query doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Sadly, still getting "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)".

Comment: Added another method with a note to check your meta key value as well. It seems odd to have wp_wp_kc_* as a meta key.

Comment: The meta key value is correct. This seems to work, thank you!

SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_wp_kc_last_active_time' AND DATEDIFF( NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(meta_value) ) > 60;